# Changing the value of a printed variable in a table

Tags: java, loops, tabular

I have an assignment to create a multiplications table using loops and the first column is supposed to go from 1-10 with an 'x' on the top left corner. This is my program:

```
public class s {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        for (int b = 0; b <= a; b++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 1; c++) {
                System.out.printf ("%3d | ", + b*c );
            }
        }
        System.out.println ();
        for (int d = 5; d < a; d++) {
            System.out.printf ("-------------");
        }
        System.out.println ("");
        for (int e = 1; e <= a; e++) {
            for (int c = 0; c <= a; c++) {
                System.out.printf ("%3d | ", e*c );
            }
            System.out.println ();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints all zeros on the first column but I want it to go x, 1, 2, 3, etc. How do I change these values?

Sorry if there are any formatting mistakes or anything, I'm just as new to Stack Overflow as I am to Java but I'm glad I found you.

Comment: Rather than apologize for "formatting mistakes", better would be to post well-formatted code.

Comment: Tell me what I did wrong and I'll learn from it. If I was aware of any mistakes I'd fix them before posting. This is just unconstructive.

Comment: Your code is all left-justified -- is that how your code is in real life? Has your instructor given you instructions on how to indent Java code? This is not just for creating pretty code, but rather its for creating readable code that is easier to understand and debug. Please fix this. This will help you as well as us, since if we can read and understand your code, we can better understand what problems you may be having with it.

Comment: I've formatted your code for you this time, but again, please do this yourself in your future questions.

Comment: I appreciate it and I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is already very close to working.  The only issue you had is trying to include the left column inside the for loops (which are dedicated to printing the multiplication values).  The general form should be:

```
System.out.printf(... left hand label ...);
for (col counter ...)
   System.out.printf(... value based on col ... );
System.out.println();
```

The adjusted code is:

```
public class s {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        System.out.printf("%3s | ", "x");
        for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d | ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("----+");
        for (int d = 0; d < a; d++) {
            System.out.printf("-----+");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int e = 1; e <= a; e++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d | ", e);
            for (int c = 1; c <= a; c++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d | ", e * c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I would also encourage you to use class names that start with a capital letter (by convention class names should be capitalized).